# PHP - Undeclared variable after require

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a php site, but I have a problem where I can't use included variables in included files!

index.php

```
<?php
require 'core/init.php';
?>
```

init.php

```
<?php
require 'config.php';

require 'db/connect.php';
?>
```

config.php

```
<?php
// Config
// The Title of the site
$site_title = 'php-site';
$site_desc = 'A awesome PHP site!';
$site_keywords = 'php, html5, css3, awesome';
$site_author = 'erty5000';

// Database - MySQL
// MySQL host
$db_host = 'localhost';

// MySQL username
$db_username = 'myuser';

// MySQL password
$db_password = 'mypassword';

// MySQL database
$db_database = 'mydb';

// Error to display at the top of the page if a connection problem occured
$db_connect_error = 'Sorry, we\'re experiencing connection problems.';
?>
```

connect.php

```
<?php
mysql_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_password) or die($db_connection_error);
mysql_select_db($db_database) or die($db_connection_error);
?>
```

The errors I get is

```
Notice: Undefined variable: db_host in C:\xampp\htdocs\w\php-site\core\db\connect.php on line 2

Notice: Undefined variable: db_username in C:\xampp\htdocs\w\php-site\core\db\connect.php on line 2

Notice: Undefined variable: db_password in C:\xampp\htdocs\w\php-site\core\db\connect.php on line 2

Warning: mysql_connect(): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO) in C:\xampp\htdocs\w\php-site\core\db\connect.php on line 2

Notice: Undefined variable: db_connection_error in C:\xampp\htdocs\w\php-site\core\db\connect.php on line 2
```

Sorry for such a long post, but I'm really hoping someone could help me!

Comment: And what's in `db\connect.php`?

Comment: Sorry added connect.php now

Comment: What if you replace `require 'config.php';` by `require __DIR__ . '/config.php';`?

Comment: Worked!! Thank you very much Niko!! :)

Comment: You're welcome! I've posted an answer with a bit more of an explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have another file named `config.php` either on the include path or in the directory of `index.php`. A explained [in the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php):

> Files are included based on the file path given or, if none is given, the include_path specified. If the file isn't found in the include_path, include will finally check in the calling script's own directory and the current working directory before failing.

This problem can be easily solved by specifying the absolute path to the file, i.e.:

```
require(__DIR__ .'/config.php');
```